# event stop propogation is not applying when divs are overlapped

Tags: javascript, event-propagation

When i upload image for both masks & when i drag the part B of below image , than Part C & D also Dragging, but it should't happen..... because Part **AB** are in one div and Part **CD** are in another DIV or am i doing something wrong with `event stoppropogation` ?

[video link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aLoQV3CvEai06NDCN1XniCY3GVOST8e-/view)

https://codepen.io/kidsdial/pen/OdwWQo

[image]

```js
fileupa.onchange = e => {
 target_imga.src = URL.createObjectURL(fileupa.files[0]);   
}

fileupb.onchange = e => {
 target_imgb.src = URL.createObjectURL(fileupb.files[0]);   
}

let prevX = 0, prevY = 0,translateX = 0, translateY = 0, scale = 1, zoomFactor = 0.1;

function onDragStart(evt) {
  if (evt.dataTransfer && evt.dataTransfer.setDragImage) {
evt.dataTransfer.setDragImage(evt.target.nextElementSibling, 0, 0);
  }
  prevX = evt.clientX;
  prevY = evt.clientY;
}

function onDragOver(evt) {
  translateX += evt.clientX - prevX;
  translateY += evt.clientY - prevY;
  prevX = evt.clientX;
  prevY = evt.clientY;
  updateStyle();
  
}

function updateStyle() 
{ 
let transform = "translate(" +translateX+ "px, "+ translateY + "px) scale("+scale+")"; 

if(document.querySelector('#uploadedImg img'))
document.querySelector('#uploadedImg img').style.transform = transform;

  if (document.getElementById("check").checked) {
    event.stopPropagation();
  }

}

function onDragOverSec(evt) {
  translateX += evt.clientX - prevX;
  translateY += evt.clientY - prevY;
  prevX = evt.clientX;
  prevY = evt.clientY;
  updateStyleSec();
}

function updateStyleSec() 
{ 
let transform = "translate(" +translateX+ "px, "+ translateY + "px) scale("+scale+")"; 

if(document.querySelector('#uploadedImg2 img'))
document.querySelector('#uploadedImg2 img').style.transform = transform;
}
```

```css
.container {
    border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
    width: 612px;
    height: 612px;
    position:relative;
 background:silver;
}

.customa {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  cursor: pointer; 
  position: relative;
    top: 350px;
    z-index: 1;
    left: -40px;
}

.customb {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  cursor: pointer; 
  position: relative;
    top: 350px;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 80px;
}

.masked-imga

{
  
  -webkit-mask-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNwNC.png);
  mask-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNwNC.png);
  -webkit-mask-position: center center;
  mask-position: center center;
  -webkit-mask-repeat: no-repeat;
  mask-repeat: no-repeat;  
  
  width: 259px;
  height: 278px;
  position: absolute;
 top: 221px;
 left: 23px; 
}


.masked-imgb 
{
  -webkit-mask-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdJSg.png);
  mask-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdJSg.png);
  -webkit-mask-position: center center;
  mask-position: center center;
  -webkit-mask-repeat: no-repeat;
  mask-repeat: no-repeat;  
  
    width: 416px;
    height: 388px;
  
    position: absolute;
 top: 111px;
 left: 173px; 
}

.minaimga
{
  display: block;
  background-color: white;
  height: 278px;
}

.minaimgb 
{
  display: block;
  background-color: white;
  height: 388px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

Stop propagation:
<input type="checkbox" id="check">


<label for="fileupa" class="customa">
    Upload Image
  </label>
  <input id="fileupa"  type="file" style="display:none;">
  
  
  <label for="fileupb" class="customb">
     Upload Image
  </label>
  <input id="fileupb"  type="file" style="display:none;">

<div class="minaimg masked-imga"   ondragover="onDragOver(event)"ondragover="onDragOver(event)" >
  <div draggable="true" ondragstart="onDragStart(event)" id="uploadedImg">
    <div class="minaimga">
     
      <img id="target_imga"  alt="">

      <div></div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="minaimg masked-imgb"   ondragover="onDragOverSec(event)"ondragover="onDragOver(event)" >
  <div draggable="true" ondragstart="onDragStart(event)" id="uploadedImg2">
    <div class="minaimgb">
    
      <img id="target_imgb"  alt="">

      <div></div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</div>
```

Please let me know if you need any other information regarding this question.....

Please help me to find solution.....

Thanks in Advance....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, instead of having two handlers for the `onDragOver` and the `updateStyle` you can just use the same and store the node that is being dragged in a variable.

```
let prevX = 0,
    prevY = 0,
    translateX = 0,
    translateY = 0,
    scale = 1,
    zoomFactor = 0.1,
    draggedElement = null;

function onDragStart(evt) {
  if (evt.dataTransfer && evt.dataTransfer.setDragImage) {
    evt.dataTransfer.setDragImage(evt.target.nextElementSibling, 0, 0);
  }
  prevX = evt.clientX;
  prevY = evt.clientY;
  draggedElement = evt.target;
}
function onDragEnd() {
  draggedElement = null;
}

function onDragOver(evt) {
  translateX += evt.clientX - prevX;
  translateY += evt.clientY - prevY;
  prevX = evt.clientX;
  prevY = evt.clientY;
  updateStyle();
}

function updateStyle() {
  if (!draggedElement) return;
  let transform = `translate(${translateX}px, ${translateY}px) scale(${scale})`;

  draggedElement.style.transform = transform;
}
```

This should also prevent from dragging both at the same time.

It would be even better if you could create a [`clip-path`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path) for each shape and use that.

See a crude approximation (*made with [clippy](https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/)*) at https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gqjWVG but you could use an SVG file for the clip-path and skip the masking altogether.

Comment: Thanks , This solution is working fine....my senior suggested to go for `mask`, so i used mask.... sorry, i am new to clip-path & svg , i have thousands of [mask images like these](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6m3N.png) , so may i go with clip-path or svg ?

Comment: @vickeycolors If working with mask is fine the go for that. If you decide to go the `clip-path` direction then and svg will give finer control. (*might be a big task though to convert all your masks to svg paths - not just svg containing the png file*)

Comment: Mask did't gave results as expected, so only i posted this question.... You gave the solution through `clip-path` , is it possible to get an answer for this question through mask also ?

Comment: even i saw that [clippy link](https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/) before only, but i did't understood how to convert to values as you did : `-webkit-clip-path: polygon(42% 100%, 48% 97%, 57% 92%, 65% 86%, 72% 79%, 81% 71%, 88% 60%, 95% 50%, 99% 40%, 100% 36%, 100% 20%, 98% 13%, 94% 7%, 91% 3%, 85% 1%, 79% 0%,  );` can you please guide me on how you did that ?

Comment: @vickeycolors for the clippy you can see in the right sidebar that you can (1) add a custom image background - the image you want to approximate. (2) give the image dimensions (3) from the top right section select "polygon" and then start clicking around the shape you want to approcimate. (4) at the bottom you can see the css `clip-path` property and its value you need to use.

Comment: I did like [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/16b2b7uegSdngvxjVmkwFrx-PxMVZGT74/view) , is that correct way ?

Comment: @vickeycolors basically yes (*that is what i did*) but you should put the dots a bit outside the actual shape as the clip will clip the image it is applied to. So the polygon will show if it falls inside the mask.

Comment: Thanks for your time, so i have to do the same thing for all the thousands of mask images i have.... it will become manual, is there any dynamic way - either `Mask , clip or svg` anywhere or just with javascript code ?

Comment: @vickeycolors The process is called tracing a bitmap. You could use vector software like inkscape (see https://www.wikihow.com/Trace-an-Image-Using-Inkscape). But since you have a senior make sure they are ok with any of those options or perhaps they have other suggestions to offer.

Comment: Sure, so if you are in my position, which one you choose - `mask , clip, svg or inkscape` ?

Comment: I do not know your complete use case so i could not offer such suggestions. Keep in mind though that `mask` and `clip-path` are CSS properties. SVG is a file format that can work with `clip-path` and InkScape is a software that allows you to create vector (.svg) files.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i am bit clear now.... As this [clippy](https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/) link will do for clip-path, can you suggest me links for `Mask & svg` ?